# TypeScript Express - I cannot use router in constructor using methods

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to seperate router in my App class. When I try following code, the response to "/rates" is pending forever:

```js
class App {
  ...

  public app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.initControllers();
  }

  private initControllers() {
    const rc = new RatesController();
    this.app.use("/", rc.router);
  }

  ...
}
```

and here's my RatesController:

```js
class RatesController {
  public router = express.Router();

  constructor() {
    this.initRoutes();
  }

  private initRoutes() {
    this.router.get("/rates", this.getRates);
  }

  getRates = (req, res) => {
    res.send("rates controller");
  }
}

export default RatesController;
```

what I tried:

```js
class App {
  ...

  public app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();

    const rc = new RatesController();
    this.app.use("/", rc.router);
  }

  ...
}
```

The above code works as I expected (it returns "rates controller"), but I still want to separate the initializing controllers part.

What should I do?

(I was following this tutorial: https://wanago.io/2018/12/03/typescript-express-tutorial-routing-controllers-middleware/)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Is the request forever pending? What do you mean by "separate the initializing controllers"?

Comment: He means refactor the initialization out of the app constructor into an initialise method. That code looks like it should work to me. Are you sure there is no other change? console.log in the handler to see if it is being called.